# Quantum entanglement and a possible loophole for FTL communication?

Tags: quantum-entanglement, faster-than-light

Does affecting particle {a} in such a way that it moves cause particle {b} to move?
If so can we instead of measuring the particles, have them in a box that is made of sensors, such that if the particle interacts with it, it shows as "on"? Then using a series of these entangled particles and boxes communicate in binary. So light years away Particle {a} is interacted with, moved, and in turn particle {b} moves and touches the sensor.

Comment: it does not work that way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a good question, but it has been thought of and it does not work: Although measuring (a) has an effect on the wavefunction of (b), it is in such a way that person (b) cannot tell that (a) has measured the particle, so no FTL communication is possible.